# Threadsafety of SimpleTimeLimiter

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I want to use com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter from guava in my server applications.

Can I create a singleton instance of SimpleTimeLimiter for the use in several classes?

Is the call of its method callWithTimeout() thread safe?

Comment: Are you refering to the Guava class?

Comment: thanks for your question, I've adapted my question therefore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sources of SimpleTimeLimiter looks perfectly thread safe for me. There are actually no place there to break thread safety, while executor you are passing is thread safe.